# Parameterize line to correspond to t values

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametrization

Parameterize the line through P=(−3,−1) and Q=(0,7) so that the points P and Q correspond to the parameter values t=13 and 16.

I have found the direction vector <3,8> and then have plugged in to find the following:

r=<-3,-1> +t<3,8>

x=3t-3
y=8t-1

I am lost as to the next steps to scale this appropriately to come up with the correct equation.

Comment: Do you recall learning how to find the equation of a line given the coordinates of two points on the line? Well, find the equation of $x(t)$ given two values of $(t,x)$, namely, $(13,-3)$ and $(16,0)$. Find the slope, use the point-slope equation to find $x$ as a function of $t$. Repeat for $y$.

Comment: I'm not quite following. y-y=m(x-x)...so would I change that to x-x=m(t-t)?

Comment: if I have x-x=(t-t)a, and then y-y=(t-t)b I get: -3 = -3a, a=1. For y: -1-7=-3b, b=8/3.

Comment: Yes. $x-x_0=m_x(t-t_0)$ and $y-y_0=m_y(t-t_0)$. You can then turn that into vector form.

Comment: Also, $m_x=(x_1-x_0)/(t_1-t_0)$ and $m_y=(y_1-y_0)/(t_1-t_0)$.

Comment: I believe I have the correct answer now (thank you!) now to figure out how to input this into a format this online program accepts, ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach beginning with what you started.

$$r=\langle -3,-1\rangle+t\langle 3,8 \rangle$$

Now this takes us from the first to the second point too quickly, in one unit of $t$ when it should take three units of $t$. So we replace $t$ with $t/3$ to get

$$r=\langle -3,-1\rangle+\frac{t}{3}\langle 3,8 \rangle$$

$$r=\langle -3,-1\rangle+t\left\langle 1,\frac{8}{3} \right\rangle$$

But now, we are arriving at the second point when $t=3$ which is $13$ units of $t$ too soon. So we should delay by $13$ units of $t$ so we arrive when $t=16$.

$$r=\langle -3,-1\rangle+(t-13)\left\langle 1,\frac{8}{3} \right\rangle$$

$$r=\langle -3,-1\rangle+t\left\langle 1,\frac{8}{3} \right\rangle-13\left\langle 1,\frac{8}{3} \right\rangle$$

$$r=\left\langle -16,-\frac{107}{3}\right\rangle+t\left\langle 1,\frac{8}{3} \right\rangle$$

**ADDENDUM:**

Note that all of this may be summarized in a formula.

If for $t_0<t_1$, $r(t)$ is a linear function satisfying $r(t_0)=\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $r(t_1)=\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ and if $t_0\le t\le t_1$ then

$$ r(t)=\langle x_0,y_0\rangle+\frac{t-t_0}{t_1-t_0}\langle x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0\rangle $$

Comment: YES! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum...this explanation and formula make 100% sense to me. You've saved my life - big test today!

Answer (score 1):

Any straight line can be written in parametric equations x= At+ B, y= Ct+ D.  We want the point (-3, -1) to correspond to t= 13.  That is, we want 13A+ B= -3 and 13C+ D= -1.
We want the point (0, 7) to correspond to t= 16  That is, we want 16A+ B= 0 and 16C+ D= 7.

Solve the equations 13A+ B= -3 and 16A+ B= 0 for A and B.
Solve the equations 13C+ D= -1 and 16C+ D= 7 for C and D.