# Parameterize a line corresponding to t values

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

> Parameterize the line that passes through $P(2,-2)$ and $Q(6,2)$ so that the points $P$ and $Q$ correspond to the parameter values $t=11$ and $t=12$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: The parametric equations of a line are in the form $$\left\{\begin{align}x&=x_1+t\Delta x\\
y&=y_1+t\Delta y,\end{align}\right.$$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point located on the line and $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$ is the slope of the line.

Comment: Honestly, my math professor never went over this material. This is a homework problem that's due tonight and it's the last one I have left. Is there any way you could work it out and show me how to solve a problem like this?

Comment: Suppose you have some point $(x_1,y_1)$ that is on your line.  Adding $11$ multiples of some vector $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$ gets you to $P$, and adding $12$ multiples of that same vector gets you to $Q$.

Comment: See [Parameterize line to correspond to t values](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293161)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a(t-11)+2,y=b(t-12)-2$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants

Now set $t=12$ to find $a,b$

Comment: I'm still confused trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equations of a line are in the form $$\left\{\begin{align}x&=x_1+t\Delta x\\
y&=y_1+t\Delta y,\end{align}\right.$$ where $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$ is the slope of the line and $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point located on the line.

Substituting $t=11$, we get $$\left\{\begin{align}2&=x_1+11\Delta x\\-2&=y_1+11\Delta y.\end{align}\right.$$

Substituting $t=12$, we get $$\left\{\begin{align}6&=x_1+12\Delta x\\2&=y_1+12\Delta y.\end{align}\right.$$

You now have two systems of two equations -- one involving $x_1$ and $\Delta x$, and the other involving $y_1$ and $\Delta y$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: iIve never even seen a problem like this so I'm going to be honest and say no. I'm not really sure what to do next.

Comment: Solving systems of linear equations is something taught _well_ before you are taught how to parameterize a line.

Comment: My professor hasn't taught us anything this semester. We are just given problems online and I've been teaching myself through youtube videos. I'm just confused on how to solve this problem and that's why I posted it to see if someone could help show me how to understand how to solve it.

Comment: I am assuming that solving systems of equations is not something that is taught in your current math course, but perhaps in a math course three years ago.

Comment: I'm not trying to just get an answer. I simply don't know how to solve the problem and I know i'll most likely see a problem like this on the final exam. I'm just asking for help.

Comment: Have you tried querying "_solving linear systems_"?

Comment: The homework assignment that this problem is in is due in 38 minutes. Ive been trying for an hour to solve it and I don't have time to keep looking up stuff that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrization of the line PQ is given by $Qt+(1-t)P$ where $0\leq t\leq 1.$ Therefore parametrization of PQ is then
$r(t)=(4t+2, 4t-2), 0\leq t\leq 1.$ Since you want to shift $t=0, t=1$ to $t=11, t=12$ respectively replace in $r(t)$ by $r(t-11)$ and required parametrization is $r^*(t)=(4t-42, 4t-46).$

Answer (score 0):

Parameterizing a line means that you can write the co-ordinates of every point on the line in the form $x=at+b$ and $y=ct+d$. We have to find the values of $a, b, c, d$ from the co-ordinates of $P,Q$ and the values $t=11, 12$ at those points.

Looking at the $x$ co-ordinates of $P$ and $Q$ we see that

$+2=11a+b$
$+6=12a+b$

Subtracting the 1st equation from the 2nd we get $4=a$. Substituting this value into the 2nd equation we find $6=12*4+b=48+b$ so $b=-42$.

Then we do the same thing for the $y$ co-ordinates of $P, Q$ :

$-2=11c+d$
$+2=12c+d$

Subtracting the 1st equation from the 2nd again we get $4=c$ and substituting this value into the 2nd equation $+2=12*4+d=48+d$ so $d=-46$.

So the co-ordinates of any point on the line are

$x=4t-42=2(2t-21)$
$y=4t-46=2(2t-23)$

*Check :* When $t=11$ we get $x=2(22-21)=2$ and $y=2(22-23)=-2$ for $P$ and when $t=12$ we get $x=2(24-21)=6$ and $y=2(24-23)=2$ for $Q$.